# How to insert values into point array in postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, sql

How to insert values into array of point in postgreSQL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you mean arrays?

```
insert into fieldname values ('{"(1,2)","(2,3)"}')
```

Naturally, this is [documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/arrays.html).